# VS Code перестает работать IntelliSense после редактирования svg

Tags: visual-studio-code

Открываю  **svg** меняю цвет в **path fill**  перестает работать **IntelliSense** , например открываю **css** - и не предлагает подсказки для свойств, то же и  в **js** - начинает работать только после перегрузки VS Codе.

Пример, так после редактирования **svg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установленные плагины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить? Может есть какие-то плагины для фикса?

Спасибо!

Comment: Уже нашли решение проблемы? Тоже самое и у меня(

Comment: [Вам сюда!](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)